# Toolbar menuitem text area height

Tags: android, xamarin, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

I have a toolbar like this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:elevation="4dp"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

And menu defined

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
  <item
      android:id="@+id/action_1"
     android:title="@string/action1"
      app:showAsAction="always"/>
  <item
   android:id="@+id/action_2"
    android:title="@string/action2"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
  <item
    android:id="@+id/action_3"
    android:title="@string/action3"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
  <item
      android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
      android:title="search"
      app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
      app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"/>
  <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

And so far it looks like this.

[image]

Action3 title is

> foo\n-\nfoo

so it takes 3 lines and does not fit. How do I change MenuItem height so it can display 3 lines of text?